# How can I limit the file size when I try to upload files via PHP parse SDK?

Tags: php, file, parse-platform, upload

I'm trying to upload files to the parse SDK cloud, and technically it works, but now I want to limit the maximum file size that a user will be able to upload. This is the code:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {

    // save file to Parse
    $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
    $file->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `$_FILES` array you will see that there is a piece of data passed with each called `$_FILES['image']['size']`

If you want to limit the size at the PHP end then just test that field

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
    if ( $_FILES['image']['size'] < 10000 ) {
        // save file to Parse
        $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
                   file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
                   $_FILES['image']['name']  );
        $file->save();
     } else {
         // return some sort of error
     }
}
```

Just remember that the `$_FILES['image']['size']` is recorded in BYTES.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an if statement and get the size of the file

```
$_FILES['image']['size']
//The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
```

something like

```
if($_FILES['image']['size'] < 10000000)
{
    // save file to Parse
    $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image' ['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
    $file->save();
}
else
{
    //Tell user that the file is too big, however you prefer
}
```

Client side stuff:
Straight from the PHP documentation:

```
<!-- The data encoding type, enctype, MUST be specified as below -->
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

> The **URL** in the above example should be replaced, and point to a
>   PHP file.
>
> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the
>   file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by
>   PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the
>   trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that
>   it was too large and the transfer failed. Keep in mind: fooling this
>   setting on the browser side is quite easy, so never rely on files with
>   a greater size being blocked by this feature. It is merely a
>   convenience feature for users on the client side of the application.
>   The PHP settings (on the server side) for maximum-size, however,
>   cannot be fooled.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful

Answer (score 0):

try this way,

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']) {
if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 10485760) { //10 MB (size is also in bytes)
    // File too big
} else {
     $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
               file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
               $_FILES['image']['name']  );
     $file->save();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the file size before you parse the file. See below:

```
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
        $maxsize    = 2097152; // 2MB 

        if(($_FILES['image']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["image"]["size"] == 0)) {
            $message = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.'; 
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$message.'");</script>'; 
        }

        // save file to Parse
        $file = ParseFile::createFromData( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), $_FILES['image']['name']  );
        $file->save();
    }
```